# Storage solution for oxygen sensitive liquid chemicals?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I'm needing to transfer oxygen sensitive liquid chemicals from a 5 litre bottle to many 100ml storage solutions. Since I'm transferring a large quantity I plan on operating within an inert atmosphere glove box (atmosphere being nitrogen), but I need to make sure that what the storage solution I am transferring to can be effectively sealed so no oxgyen seeps through over time once in storage.

Like many packaged goods I want to make sure that nitrogen is sealed within the storage solution (so vacuum sealing wouldn't be appropriate). The only thing I can think of at the moment is storing in 100ml bottles, but I'm not sure how to completely seal bottle caps, such that is done for commerical products like milk.

Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You state your [aliquots](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00218) are of $\pu{100 mL}$ each.

If eventually *all* of this volume will be used *at once*, like for the preparation of a standard solution, then transfer into an [ampoule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampoule) may be an option.  Degass/evacuate and purge the then still empty container attached to a [Schlenk line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlenk_line) (a recently discovered [tutorial page](https://schlenklinesurvivalguide.com/)), then cannulate the solution from your storage container of $\pu{5 L}$ into the smaller ones.  Then flame seal these small containers.

If you aim to draw multiple times small portions from these containers of $\pu{100 mL}$, then sealing threaded flasks with a septum is *an option*:

[image]

(edited photo, original from [SigmaAldrich's catalogue](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/supelco/23230u?context=product))

At least once pierced, these do not close *as good* as their bottles seen on BuLi and other reagent solution storage flasks with a [Sure/Seal(TM)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/technical-documents/technical-article/chemistry-and-synthesis/organic-reaction-toolbox/sureseal) cap. But this is a general problem all septa face (especially over time, exposed to corrosive reagents).  Crimp caps ([example](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/supelco/33110u)) are more frequently seen for smaller vials/microwave tubes.

Comment: A lot of great ideas here. One that I've had in mind prior to your response was to transfer the liquid from the 5 litre bottle to 100ml plastic bottles within an inert atmosphere glove box, but then use an electronic induction sealer within the glove box to seal a foil liner over the 100ml bottle after directly flushing with nitrogen, then just leave a standard cap over that. Like that is typically done for sealed commerical liquid medicines. The intention is to essentionally repackage the solution from a 5 litre bottle to many 100ml bottles without any chance of oxidation.

Comment: What do you intend to strore (a solvent compatibility chart like [this](https://rubber-group.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Chemical-Compatibility.pdf) may be one early indication)? I have some preference for glass bottles for that their resistance to chemicals is broader than plastics/easier cleaning, that they (*gradually*) may be oven dried, their lesser permeability for water/air across their walls, withstand pressure, and that may be reused multiple times, and then recycled. But it is possible to put a lid on the bottle, and this in a bag eventually vacuum sealed.

Comment: (Continuation) If you want to have some protection in the bag/between the liquid and the lid of the bottle, argon (though more expensive per litre than nitrogen) is better.  Because it denser than air, argon actually is like blanket *on top* of your solution.  The light nitrogen gas just goes up into the air, literally (sometimes a potential problem in the org chem lab when we set up a reaction to work in a water dry/oxygen less environment).